# Диапазон перемещений в сетке шестиугольников

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, математика

Построил сетку шестиугольников(11x15)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый шестиугольник имеет свои координаты вида

```
[   [0,0], [0,1], [0, 2] ... [0,14]
 [1,0], [1,1], [1, 2] ... [1,14]
    [2,0], [2,1], [2, 2] ... [2,14]
[3,0], [3,1], [3, 2] ... [3,14]
 ......
    [10,0], [10,1], ..........[10, 14]]
```

Хотелось бы сформировать условие без обхода всех гексов удовлетворяющих условию -N <= x <= -N и -N <= y <= N и проверкой расстояния до каждого.

```
// x, y координаты нижнего круга.
let x =6;
let y = 7;
let n = 3; 
function drawDistance(){
       for(let i = Math.max(0, x - n); i<= Math.min(14, x + n)) 
          for(???){
              console.log(i, j);
          }
}
```

На хабре была статья о подобном 
https://habr.com/ru/post/319644/  раздел Диапазоны перемещений, там было условие

```
max(-n, -i-n) <= j <= min(n, -i+n)
```

Проверив в ручную подобное условие - в моем случае не подошло, видимо в хабрской статье речь идет о координатах вершин, а не гексов.

Comment: "что бы в диапазон N шагов вывести все шестиугольники" - что это значит?

Comment: @Igor, вывести координаты всех гексов, которые можно достичь за 2 шага.

Comment: А это background-image, или реальные элементы на странице... SVG ?

Comment: Очень хорошо. Что значит "вывести шестиугольник"?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, да svg, каждый polygon имеет ID соответствующий его координате

Comment: @Igor, имелось ввиду координаты шестиугольника - строку и столбец)

Comment: собственно при чем тут шестиугольники, если задача о координатах на плоскости?

Comment: Укажите, как осуществляется нумерация шестиугольников (способов немало)

Comment: рука-лицо. это "шашки"

Comment: @MBo указал в посте

Comment: -- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/367302 -- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44812 -- http://bennycheung.github.io/interactive-hex-world-map-using-d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно выполнять обход в ширину (BFS) с ограничением по глубине.

Причём из ячейки `[i,j]` чётного ряда можно пойти в

```
     [i-1, j]  [i-1, j+1]  
  [i, j-1]       [i, j+1] 
     [i+1, j]  [i+1, j+1]
```

а из нечётного в

```
     [i-1, j-1]  [i-1, j]  
  [i, j-1]       [i, j+1] 
     [i+1, j-1]  [i+1, j]
```

А если объединить в одно:

```
  s = i & 1   

     [i-1, j - s]  [i-1, j+1 - s]  
  [i, j-1]                    [i, j+1] 
     [i+1, j - s]  [i+1, j+1 - s]
```

Кроме того, можно написать функцию, которая для данной нумерации вычисляет расстояние между ячейками [a,b] и [c,d], и обходить в двойном цикле "прямоугольник" заведомо достаточного размера, отбрасывая лишнее (лишних ячеек будет всего 1/6 часть)

**[Edit]**
Много по гекс. решётка собрано тут: [Hexagonal Grids](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Приведённая нумерация соответствует `“even-r” horizontal layout
shoves even rows right` c инверсией X/Y. Однако большинство расчётов автор проводит в "кубических" координатах x,y,z, а для других систем координат использует функции преобразования туда-сюда.

Для получения нужного [range](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#range) он предлагает такую функцию, обходящую только нужный шестиугольник:

```
var results = []
for each -N ≤ x ≤ +N:
    for each max(-N, -x-N) ≤ y ≤ min(+N, -x+N):
        var z = -x-y
        results.append(cube_add(center, Cube(x, y, z)))
```

[Страница с кодом](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html), если чего-то не описано

**[Edit2]**
Вот, вроде так работает - baser: начальный ряд (достаточно его чётности), выдаются смещения.

```
def cube_to_evenr(x, y, z, baser):
    s = baser & 1
    if (baser & 1) != (z & 1):
       s = 0
    col = x + (z + (z&1)) // 2 - s
    row = z
    return (row, col)

def hexrange(dist, baser):
    results = []
    for x in range(-dist, dist + 1):
        for y in range(max(-dist, -x-dist), min(dist+ 1, -x+dist+1)):
            z = -x-y
            results.append(cube_to_evenr(x, y, z, baser))
    results.sort()
    return results

print(hexrange(1, 0))
print(hexrange(1, 1))
print(hexrange(2, 0))
print(hexrange(2, 1))

[(-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0)]
[(-2, -1), (-2, 0), (-2, 1), 
 (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, 2), 
 (0, -2), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), 
 (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), 
 (2, -1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
[(-2, -1), (-2, 0), (-2, 1), 
 (-1, -2), (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), 
 (0, -2), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), 
 (1, -2), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), 
 (2, -1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: мне чутье подсказывает что тут нужна какая то вариация манхэттеновского расстояния

Comment: Видимо да, какая-то его вариация, но правильные границы подобрать не получается. Перекосы то в одну сторону то в другую.

Comment: @MBo, я проверял указанные интервалы.Видимо автор в статье использует кубические координаты для углов гексов, а не сами гексы, т.к. в таком случае у на попадут лишние поля.

Comment: @KordDEM По рисунку-то выглядит всё нормально, если водить по нему мышкой. Понимание, что является количеством шагов до ячейки у вас с тем автором совпадает?

Comment: @MBo, да совпадает. Я смотрел перевод и более полный вариант этой статьи на хабре и пробовал указанный диапазон. Собственно потому и решился задать тут вопрос, т.к. у меня не сходится с предложенной формулой.

Comment: @KordDEM По-быстрому сделал [на Python](https://ideone.com/SgyInV) и похоже, что в тройных координатах работает верно, а вот в evenr триплет переводится криво - формула должна зависеть от чётности начального ряда.